# Access controls created programmatically on form1 from form2

Tags: c#

In `form1`, i am creating some controls programmatically like below:

```
 XtraTabPage xtp = new XtraTabPage();
        xtp.Name = "abc";
        xtp.Text = "abc";
        xtraTabControl1.TabPages.Add(xtp);
```

in `form2`, i would like to access xtp and change the text property. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is very bad approach but not really sure why the requirement end up like this. But to achieve this, 
Step 1. In form1, define 'internal XtraTabPage xtp;' at the very top of the code file (at variable declaration section). Then create instance as 'xtp = new XtraTabPage()'. The whole idea here is to define it globally in form 1 as public / internal accessibility.
Step 2. In form2, get access to instance of form1 (form1 frm = new form1()) then access it as frm.xtp to set the properties.

Comment: The problem is that for every button click, i will be creating a new tabpage and i would like to access all these tabpages in form2

Comment: Ok. So did you try the approach i mentioned?

Comment: The XtraTabPage xtp is created programmatically, How can i access it in form1.designer.cs? The form1.designer.cs  seems to only have controls added via designer

Comment: Can you give more details on how are creating XtraTabPage in form1.

Comment: It is done as shown below:                                                                              
 private void barButtonItem18_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            XtraTabPage xtp = new XtraTabPage();
            xtp.Name = name;
            xtp.Text = name;
            xtraTabControl1.TabPages.Add(xtp);
        }

Comment: check the updated solution or answer. Mainly the idea is to define it xtp globally instead of defining it inside itemclick event

Comment: tried the above solution but i get "object reference not set to an instance of an object error"